# How to access Gmail delegator's email

Tags: gmail-api

Let's say Bob has delegated his Gmail account to Alice.  I have authenticated Alice using OAuth 2.0 and have an access token.  How can I access Bob's email instead of Alice's?  I was assuming that this would work:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/bob@gmail.com/labels?access_token=<alicetokenhere>
```

This just gives me a 403 error.  I am aware of how to do this using a service account, but these users are not part of a Google Apps domain, just individual users.  Can it be done?

Comment: How exactly has bob delegated his Gmail account to Alice?  No to my knowledge this can not be done.

Comment: Not sure if this is a new feature or not, I just heard of it myself.  See here: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Gmail API doesn't currently support delegation - Gmail delegation only works through the web UI, or using [GSSMO](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/153866) (for G Suite users).

The proper way to do this using an API (or IMAP) client is to get Bob to authorize your app using OAuth as well.